# How to make element disappear from html DOM tree when inspecting?

Tags: html, dom, element, shadow-dom, inspect

I've learnt that **Shadow DOM** tree with its elements can be viewed or inspected in developer tools after making some adjustments in settings (*'show shadow DOM'* checkbox).

Is there any way to have element in tree but not visible outside. I mean, JS needs to use that element later.

Element has **no** visual appearance on the page and will never have. It serves as a *DOM container* for some information.

Comment: You mean not visible to anyone who pokes around using dev tools? No, that is not possible.

Comment: So, I can't have an element hidden from browser. What I want is some kind of place in the DOM to store a tiny slice of data, to manipulate later on. Is this task considered to be impossible.

Comment: Your normal “data storage” mechanism inside a script would be variables; what you need something else for, why you think putting the data in the DOM somehow would be a good idea, etc. - largely unclear. Apparently this also has a component of “hiding” the data from someone, but why/who from - also unclear.

Comment: Question is: where to store that variables? Imagine, you have response from any API, you have to keep that info somewhere. Cookie? WebStorage? I thought I could have third option: somewhere in the DOM. Maybe there is another layer I'm missing.

Comment: Sure you can store it in multiple different places; question would be, what are your _requirements_ …? If you plan on storing the data somewhere where the user of the site doesn’t ever get access to it, then all of those are not suitable.

Comment: I guess they are not suitable, cause all of them sort of **client-side** storages, which implies that user *has to have* to access them. Am I right?

Comment: More or less, yes. Hiding data from the user on the client-side is not easily possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @CBroe Could you, please, give me a hint which techniques are used to make data on client more or less hard to access, if they are.

Comment: There aren’t any for all general use cases; what you can maybe do for your use case, depends on the specifics of what exactly you need, where the data comes from and who/what needs to use it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can store variables in local Storage using javascript.

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Comment: localStorage is vulnerable to XSS attacks.